# jaxbcontext.newinstance() with eclipselink MOXy hangs

Tags: json, spring, eclipselink, moxy

disclaimer: I'm incredibly amateur at all of this

I'm trying to get the project I'm working on to output JSON in addition the XML.
Originally the prior method to do so involved a method that took in an argument of Element and recursively inserted things into an object of type net.sf JSONObject to create the JSON output, and used the normal `JAXBContext`'s `Marshaller` to marshal into XML.

What I wanted was to use MOXy as my JAXB provider, and then marshal out both XML and JSON from the bindings.

Originally, when the XML was marshalled, I had:

```
jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("packageA:packageB:packageC...etc.");
```

```java
public static String marshal(JAXBContext context, JAXBElement<?> je) throws JAXBException {
    StringWriter sout = new StringWriter();
    Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.FALSE);
    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    m.marshal(je, sout);
    return sout.toString();
}
```

and then

```
JAXBElement<myObject> jaxb = 
  new JAXBElement<myObject>(myObject_QNAME, myObject.class, null, value);
return XmlResponseMessage(marshal(jc, jaxb));
}
```

(this is probably important, so I should mention that the application I'm working on uses the spring framework.)

**Also, I've read every single one of Blaise's blog posts regarding EclipseLink. Some multiple times. I just have a very shallow understanding of it and would appreciate if instead of linking me to one of his pages you explained whatever solution on it is and why it works**

That being said, I tried just including the `jaxb.properties` file in one of the packages to try to get MOXy as opposed to `JAXBElement` to get my bindings. 
however, `JAXBContext.newInstance("my list of : delimited packages")` just makes the program hang. not even an error, just hangs it. stepping through just shows the call to the EclipseLink `newInstance` method hanging. 
I've looked for many hours for solutions online. I have much too many classes to just include in a Class[], and so can't set the property by using an array of classes. which is also the reason I couldn't use the native moxy API instead of using the property file. I *think* i have EclipseLink set up correctly: I've set `eclipselink_home` in my environment variables, and added the eclipselink.jar to my buildpath.

Comment: P.S. A retroactive apology for my poor capitalization and formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE #2**

A fix for this issue has been checked into the EclipseLink 2.4.2 and 2.5.0 streams and a nightly build containing the fix can be downloaded from the following link starting **March 12, 2013**:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php

---

**UPDATE #1**

After a couple of email exchanges I think the problem you are encountering is due to the following bug.  You can use the link to track our progress on this issue.

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/402801

I'll demonstrate how it manifests itself below:

**ObjectFactory**

For the problem to occur you need to have an `@XmlElementDecl` annotation where the`name` is the same as the `substitutionHeadName`.

```java
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    @XmlElementDecl(name="foo", substitutionHeadName="foo")
    public JAXBElement<Foo> createBar(Foo foo) {
        return new JAXBElement<Foo>(new QName("foo"), Foo.class, foo);
    }

}
```

**Domain Object (Foo)**

Then on one of your domain objects you need to have an `@XmlElementRef` annotation referencing the element we defined in the `@XmlElementDecl`.

```java
public class Foo {

    @XmlElementRef(name="foo")
    public Foo foo;

}
```

**Demo**

You will see the problem when you create the `JAXBContext`.

```java
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class, ObjectFactory.class);
        System.out.println(jc.getClass());
    }

}
```

**Trace**

MOXy gets in an infinite loop adding the reference element.

```java
...
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.addReferencedElement(AnnotationsProcessor.java:3740)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.addReferencedElement(AnnotationsProcessor.java:3740)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.addReferencedElement(AnnotationsProcessor.java:3740)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.addReferencedElement(AnnotationsProcessor.java:3740)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.addReferencedElement(AnnotationsProcessor.java:3740)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.addReferencedElement(AnnotationsProcessor.java:3740)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.addReferencedElement(AnnotationsProcessor.java:3740)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.addReferencedElement(AnnotationsProcessor.java:3740)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.addReferencedElement(AnnotationsProcessor.java:3740)
...
```

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

You could try using the following to create your `JAXBContext`.  It bypasses the standard JAXB impl lookup code by using native MOXy code.

```
JAXBContext jc = org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext("packageA:packageB:packageC...etc.");
```

If that works we'll know the problem is related to the impl look up code and we can go from there.

Comment: I get
The method createContext(String, ClassLoader) in the type JAXBContextFactory is not applicable for the arguments (String)
do i need to obtain a classloader from somewhere? if so how (or rather what classloader do I even get if i'm passing a bunch of packages and not a single class?)

Comment: @MiloHou - Just pass `null` in for the `ClassLoader`.

Comment: Ah ok. I wasn't sure if it was necessary or not. Should I remove the properties file that I had in one of the packages, or does it not matter? Trying that line of code still makes the program hang (both with and without the properties file). 
 
On a side note: should the JAXBContext jc be of type javax.bind.JAXBContext or org.eclipse...JAXBContext?
P.S. how long should creating the context take? before when generating xml it took only around 10 seconds ago, does the moxy jaxbcontext take longer to create? P.P.S sorry for the wall of text

Comment: @MiloHou - Have you tried creating it outside of a Spring environment?

Comment: Creating the same context or creating any context with eclipselink? I'm not sure how to even make a context outside of Spring. As far as I knew Spring just allowed me to inject dependencies, I'm just running it right now as a Junit test. Though to be honest there's probably a huge gap in understanding between my response and what you actually asked; my understanding of Spring is also kind of shallow

Comment: @MiloHou - The same `JAXBContext` created in just a main method.  Would you mind contacting me though the following link so that we can start an email discussion for this issue:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/p/contact_01.html